# Laravel save data from one form to different database tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to create a student with some courses.

[This is the Laravel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoXw0.png)

I created two different tables: a students table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('student_name');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email');
        });
    }
```

and a courses table.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('student_courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedInteger('student_id');
            $table->string('course_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

The students table creates the information of the student and saves it in the student table.

I want to save the courses into the courses table, with the student id. They should have a One to Many relationship. How can I save the different courses into the courses table with the id of the specific student?

Answer (score 0):

You can't store course name in student courses table. You need to create separate tables for courses. After that you can use foreign key for store both the data of student and courses into the student_courses table as per below.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('student_courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First create Relationship:
In User Model Create:
`public function courses(){
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
    }`

In Course Model Create:
    `public function students(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Studnet::class);
    }`
Now in your save function:

```
$course = new Course($request->all());
$user->courses()->save($course);
```